# <input type="file"> doesn't always work on iOS

Tags: html, ios, input

If I tap on an `<input type="file">` several times in a row on iOS, it will occasionally fail to pop up the "Photo Library/Take Photo/Choose File" dialog, and nothing happens. This is true even with the most basic example of `<input type="file">` on w3schools (Try opening https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file on an iPhone and hitting the "Choose File" button several times in a row - it doesn't work consistently! This happens in both Chrome and Safari on iOS)

This seems to be an iOS bug, but I can't find it documented anywhere - can anyone point me to documentation of this and/or a workaround?

Comment: Note that Chrome on iOS is still Safari under the hood. It's the Safari WebView since Apple doesn't allow other browser engines, afaik.
To your Issue: Does this also happen if you wait for the pop-up transition (animation) to complete? In my case, it only happens when I try to reopen the pop-up during the fade out transition. So you have to wait until the pop-up disappears completely. Or does this happen if you already selected a file? In this case you should set the input value to null. Because the change event does only fire on change (file name). But I guess it's just the transition issue.

Comment: You're absolutely right - the issue goes away when I make sure to wait for the transition animation to complete. I've found that adding a 100ms delay improves this somewhat (I can tap quickly and see less failures), but it's not perfect - I think I'll probably leave this as-is.